# which is suitable for wine, "sourness" or "acidity"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, adjectives, collocation

Which adjective is suitable for tastes of wine? And why?

I'd like to know which expression you usually use and if there is any difference.

---

More context: I had a chance to translate ”酸味”, which means both sour and acid, to English for a wine description. Then I wondered which word, sourness or acidity, sounds more natural for English speakers to explain the taste of wine.

Comment: Depends whether you like the taste or not, I suspect.  I'm not an oenophile, but I suspect that "tartness" is often used.

Comment: I sold wine for years in the US, and although I frequently heard the term "acidity," I've never heard "sourness" as a wine description. My boss: "Wine...if you like it, it's 'good,' if you don't ...rotgut."

Comment: Why is this a binary choice? *Sourness* and *acidity* have completely different flavours.  What about all of the other flavours that could be used to describe wine? And just because one flavour is more common, that doesn't mean the other isn't also possible. I don't think I understand the purpose of the question. (And, yes, I have had wine in which I've tasted what I could describe as sourness but not acidity. However, I wouldn't normally use either term in a general description.)

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for your quick reply. so tartness is more general?

Comment: @StuW big thanks to your professional point of view. I wonder if you personally use "sourness" for a wine description?

Comment: @JasonBassford I should've given more context, sorry. I'm a student from a translation school in Japan. And I had a chance to translate ”酸味”, which means both sour and acid, to English for a wine description. Then I wondered which word, sourness or acidity, sounds more natural for English speakers to explain the taste of wine.

Comment: @user387683 I see. It would be more common to hear *acid* when talking about wine. If I were forced at gunpoint to translate based on nothing else, I'd have a better chance of getting it right with *acid* than with *sour*. But while it seems likely that's what's meant, the particular context could indicate it's the other.

Comment: "Tartness" is less prejudicial.

Comment: It would depend somewhat on the wine.  There are styles that could be described as acidic and others (particularly some whites) that could be described as having sour elements.

Comment: I'm not sure about other countries, but I've never personally used or heard the tern "sourness" to describe wine, nor have I seen it in American wine journals like *Wine Spectator.*

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for the additional comment! Maybe as the others say, "acid" is a bit more natural to use for wine tastes for natives but I understand it mostly depends on contexts.

Comment: @HotLicks ah!! do you usually use the term?

Comment: @StuW I really appreciate your assistance. Now I'm sure I should use "acid" for wine descriptions. Are there any reason why ppl use "acid" but not "sour" for wines? Or is it just a collocation?

Comment: @user387683 - Like I said,  I'm not an oenophile.

Comment: @user387683 *Sour* is used quite often in the context of foods, or even beer (where it's become a new fad). But the sour profile that's used for those things is not something that's generally considered when it comes to wine. With the exception of some white wines (and I would find it doubtful even there), that's not a flavour that goes well it. When something tastes sour, it's supposed to be  appreciated for that (it's deliberate rather than a sign of it having gone off). It's not a subtle flavour, and it's one that, I think, would normally detract from wine. At least as we're used to it.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, but I want to know how natives use these terms. If you use "tartness" in your daily life, I would use that.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for that explanation!!!! I clearly understand how to use " sour" now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has yet suggested "dry". This is the usual description of a wine which is the opposite of "sweet" but a dry wine should not be either "sour" or "acidic" since these are both faults, as I understand it. I believe you are looking for "dry" as the translation unless you are talking about faults in wine. Notice also that "dry" is used for the same purpose when describing other drinks, hence "dry martini".

Comment: @BoldBen - Me too. I had to open all the comments to find your mention of it. And it's an important word, and not just to oenophiles; it's a marketing term too. Sometimes marketers use the term "semi-dry" to try to boost a sweet wine's appeal, because the dry types generally taste better. Port, sherry, vermouth, and many other commodities come in two varieties - dry and sweet - and you have to use the right one. Sweet vermouth in a martini, ugh.

Comment: I have provided my own answer to the question as one of English. As far as translating from Japanese, this can only be done with knowledge of the context in which the word is used. The question does not indicate whether it is meant in a positive, negative or purely scientific way.

Answer (score 3):

"Sourness" has something of a negative connotation in terms of flavor of wine. However, in other contexts, such as "sweet and sour" chicken, sour candy, or a "whiskey sour" (drink), it's not a negative description. "Acidity" is a much more common description in writing about wine. "Tart" and "tartness" are also seen in many wine flavor descriptions.

*The Wine Spectator* has an article about acidity, tartness, and other aspects of wine flavor. Here is one interesting quote: "Hipster sommeliers and wine writers who consider themselves cutting edge favor tart, tangy wine styles."

https://www.winespectator.com/articles/perceiving-acidity-in-wine

Note that "acidity" has a scientific definition, involving pH (a measurement regime involving ions and electrons in chemistry), while tartness, sourness, and similar flavor terms do not (as far as I can determine).

Comment: The remark about scientific definitions is important. If you were discussing the winemaking process in a technical way then "acidity" is more appropriate as something that is measurable, in the same way as you talk about measuring residual sugar or alcohol content, but "tartness" is fine for taste. How sour or tart something tastes depends on other flavor components as well as the pH.

Answer (score 1):

**Acidic** is the correct translation when dealing with wine.  Grapes contain malic acid, which gives them a “sour” or “tart” taste until they ripen.

The wikipedia has an article on malic acid that’s quite informative: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malic_acid

There’s a Japanese entry for malic acid: リンゴ酸

*Malum* is the Latin word for apple, so it looks like a pretty straightforward translation.

Answer (score 1):

**Acerbic** (adj.) covers both sourness and acidity.

> Of speech, manner, or temper: bitter and sharp; forthright and cutting. **Later also in literal sense of food or flavour: astringently sour or harsh-tasting.** OED

> Sour or bitter tasting; acid. [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=acerbic)

> Sour or astringent in taste
> *Lemon juice is acerbic.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/acerbic)

> Said of a sour, green wine, due to excess tannin and acidity [https://www.vindefrance.com/](https://www.vindefrance.com/wines/grape-varieties-of-france/wine-words/acerbic)

> Harsh and acidic. [Bourgogne wines Glossary](https://www.bourgogne-wines.com/glossary/acerbic,2532,9412.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD0xNTc1JmFjdGlvbj12aWV3R2xvc3NhaXJlJmlkPSZtb3Q9NXw%3D)

---

> Pinot Meunier...Makes a fairly tart, **acerbic** wine that lends a
> bright and fresh edge to Champagne. [A. Smith and J. Dodd; *The Wine
> Pocket Bible*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Wine_Pocket_Bible/MNLnDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=acerbic%20wine&pg=PT16&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> Pinot Noir is one of the world's most challenging vine varieties with
> which to make wine. It mutates easily, is susceptible to disease, and
> yields thin, pale, **acerbic** wine if the winemaker isn't careful or if the vines
> are grown in unsuitable places. [Carolyn Hammond; *Good, Better,
> Best Wines*, 2nd ed.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Good_Better_Best_Wines_2nd_Edition/5PJoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=ascerbic%20wine&pg=PT108&printsec=frontcover)  (2018)

> Gentile's 'practical canons' about the use of wine rested on the
> complexion of different sorts of wine. He notes a local **acerbic**
> wine with a wild, vinegary taste and called *bruscum* which had an
> unusual cooling property. [Roger French; *Canonical Medicine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Canonical_Medicine/OSNXEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22acerbic%20wine%22&pg=PA247&printsec=frontcover)
> (2021)

> Sour beers are at once complex and **acerbic** and wonderfully and
> painfully tart. [C. Perozzi and H. Beaune; *The Naked Pit*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Naked_Pint/erLFYbSqVvQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=acerbic%20malic%20acid&pg=PT158&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> **Acerbity** (n.)
>
> Sourness ore harshness of taste, mingled with bitterness or
> astringency.
>
> 1991   *Food & Wine* Apr. 82/3   The foods to look for are ones that
> can play off the olive **acerbity** of these textured, always tannic
> reds. OED

> Native wines, when pure, are just as good as any other for cooking
> purposes.
> It is wrong and a great mistake to underrate native wines; they have
> a little more **acerbity** than foreign wines, but are not inferior.
> [Pierre Blot; *Handbook of Practical Cookery*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Practical_Cookery/hVjCiS1BJJAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=acerbity%20of%20the%20wine&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover) (1867)

> Here and there appears a dreary inn or a wine-shop, designated by the
> withered bush beside the entrance, within which you discern a
> stone-built and sepulchral interior, where guests refresh themselves
> with sour bread and goats'-milk cheese, washed down with wine of
> dolorous **acerbity**. [Nathaniel Hawtorne; *The Marble Faun*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Works_of_Nathaniel_Hawthorne_The_mar/9Hk5AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Hawthorne%20washed%20down%20with%20dolorous%20acerbity&pg=PA212&printsec=frontcover) (1860)

Comment: Interesting historically, and although the 1991 quotation is quite elegant and meaningful, this is hardly common usage. How many people know what it means? I'm not even sure myself. Seems more an alternative to sour — with negative connotations — rather than to acidity, which need not be so. Without the context of the original, it's difficult to be sure what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

> The term **acidity** *is* used in relation to wine, whereas the word
> **sourness** *is not*.

Support for this statement can be found, for example, in this [Glossary of Wine Terms](https://www.vinology.com/wine-terms/#h-acidity-to-astringent) in which includes *acidity* but not *sourness*.

The word *sour* is general reserved for wine in which the alcohol has been oxidized to acetic acid so that it has become undrinkable. In fact, this is the chemical reaction for converting wine to [vinegar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinegar).

All wines are in the acidic range, having a pH of less than that of neutral water (pH 7). The acids that contribute to this acidity do *not* include acetic acid, but are malic acid, citric acid and tartaric acid — the last of which can crystalize out of certain white wines at low temperatures. If a wine undergoes [malolactic fermentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malolactic_fermentation), then some of the malic acid is converted to lactic acid.

Thus, although the acidity of wines is of interest, it does not in isolation indicate very much about the wine, and may or may not be evident in the taste. A more appropriate term that is applied to wines may be

> **tart**

and, indeed, the Wikipedia entry cited above illustrates its use:

> *Malolactic* conversion…
> is a process in winemaking in which **tart**-tasting malic acid, naturally
> present in grape must, is converted to softer-tasting lactic acid.

A final point is that the *perception* of acidity is altered by the sweetness of the wine, especially in white wines. This is particularly so in German Rieslings, where it is the balance of acidity and sweetness that results in their greatness. Without the acidity they would be bland and flabby. And this is also why German desert wines taste different from French Sauternes, which lack this acidity.