# Will the word sour in "sweet and sour" dish give negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

Will the word sour in "sweet and sour" dish give negative connotation? In Chinese we actually say "sweet and vinegary" dish ('糖醋' as '醋' is vinegar). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_and_sour, to quote

> The etymology of the term "Sweet and Sour" comes from the Chinese word
> "甜酸"(甜 = sweet, 酸 = sour), formally used in Chinese dishes as "糖醋“ (糖
> = sugar, 醋 = vinegar). It is commonly used in China since the Tang Dynasty (618-907) ...

When I look the word "sour" up in dictionary, it seems that except for "sweet and sour", all the other meanings all give out some unpleasant feeling, which makes me feel "sweet and sour" seem not be a good translation, e.g. why not "**sweet and vinegary**" ?

But is it the case? As English is not my native language, I am not sure the nuances of these two.

Comment: Per _Collins_, _Sweet and sour_ is used to describe Chinese food that contains both a sweet flavour and something sharp or sour such as lemon or vinegar. I don't think it carries ang negative connotation whatever.

Comment: @user405662 - I'm sure the OP is well aware of that!

Comment: Not necessarily. We speak of _sour cherries_, which are the kind used for cooking rather than eating raw, and _sour, bitter or Seville oranges_ which are used for making marmalade. English speakers are familiar with the concept of a 'sour' or 'vinegary' element adding a piquant taste to some foods.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for the comments. I am Chinese ,of course I am aware of that. My question is since English is not my native language I don't know whether "sour" will give negative connotation, since sour milk, sour wine are all about food goes bad. So I am a bit surprised you guys did NOT say "sweet and lemon" or "sweet and vinegar"

Comment: I was trying to explain that _sour_ is not necessarily a negative description, because Westerners are familiar with the concept of deliberately introducing a 'sour' element to some foods. Indeed, the word _vinegar_ comes from Latin words meaning 'sour wine'.

Comment: Thanks. BTW found a similar question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536633/which-is-suitable-for-wine-sourness-or-acidity I think who asked that was also Chinese lol

Comment: Vinegar potentially has negative connotations, as the result of wine going bad, and there are phrases like "vinegar tits" and "piss and vinegar" which is vulgar even if not insulting. I'm not sure what the question is getting at though, do you want to change the common phrase "sweet and sour" or are you asking how it became popular?

Comment: 'Sweet and sour' is a fixed phrase and carries negligible if any pejorative connotation for anyone not disliking the dish. 'Sweet and vinegary' would carry far more.

Comment: I just asked what I said in my question. I did not have any hidden questions like how it became popular or I want to change the "sweet and sour" So I don't understand why my question confused you (or got downvoted). So can you help me reword my question ?

Comment: I think that between us we have answered your question. There is nothing negative in the expression _sweet and sour_, even though in _some_ food contexts _sour_ can imply a disagreeable flavour or spoiled food.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, between us you have answered my question. So when I saw the words "I'm not sure what the question is getting at though" I was confused.

Comment: I updated my question a little. But I am not sure if that will make my question clearer. But anyway @KateBunting has answered it.

Comment: Hot & sour soup is sometimes called Hot & Pungent. Sour may have negative senses and still work just fine where it's a neutral term: sourball (tart candy), sour cream, sauerkraut.

Comment: [Sour sweets](https://www.treasureislandsweets.co.uk/sour-sweets.html) ("candy") are very popular with children in the UK.

Comment: There is *no* negative connotation for *sweet and sour* when it comes to cuisine. That's *the* name for this delicious sauce/preparation. If you change it, no one will eat your food.

Comment: I'm surprised it hasn't been spelled out explicitly, but "sweet and sour" is specifically idiomatically used for a specific type of dish common in the Westernized menus of Chinese restaurants, usually chicken, breaded, deep fried, and served in a sticky orange "sweet and sour" sauce. There is also "hot and sour" soup. These set phrases are expected and would not be off-putting, though you're also right that, especially outside of the context of food, "sour" is often negative (a "sour" person, a "sour" musical note...).

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, sour doesn't always carry a negative connotation for food, though it can, sour cream is fine, sour milk not so much.

However, in terms of describing dishes as 'sweet and sour' a menu would not describe something as sour it it was not supposed to be. Context is everything.

In addition, 'sweet and sour' has an appealing degree of alliteration, and has become a set term in English.

Comment: In 'sour milk', there is a negative **denotation** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sour): 'Something that is sour has a sharp, unpleasant taste like the taste of a lemon.'  The question is whether/to what degree this carries across as a connotation to the expression 'sweet and sour'. // I think an 'answer' needs supporting evidence, though I've just realised that the answer to this question really boils down to opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth IMO the main issue between "sour milk" and "sour cream" is one is perceived as spoiled, and the other as intentional. Aside from milk, I can't think of a similar usage of "sour" for spoilage (aside from maybe: wet laundry that has mildewed can be said to have "soured").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Maybe "sweet and sour chicken" isn't as common in the UK as it is in the US.  Here it's as common as I think "fish and chips" is in the UK.

Comment: @aparente001 " 'Sweet and sour' is a fixed phrase and carries negligible if any pejorative connotation ..." is what I commented 19 hours before your comment above. 'Sweet and sour chicken / king prawn ...' are very common (in fact perhaps becoming less so than 50 years ago) in the UK. //// My comment here is to address the confusion that << "sour milk [is not fine]" ↔ [negative connotation] >>, where the association ↔ is not specified, may well cause. 'Sour' in 'sour milk' doesn't have a negative connotation; it **really is** negative. But does this taint the usage in 'sweet and sour'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The British English definintion at your Collins link reads 'having or denoting a sharp biting taste like that of lemon juice or vinegar', it does not include the assumption that such a taste is unpleasant, so I'm comfortable with connotation being appropriate.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sour) has 'having a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, taste or smell, like a lemon, and not sweet'. 'Unpleasant' is included in the dictionary definition of some usages of the word, and so must be considered more than a connotation. // [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sour_1) has: 'with an unpleasant taste or smell, _especially_ because of no longer being fresh' [but not _solely_] [italics mine]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't agree that 'unpleasant' is definitional.

Comment: It's in the definition (of one of the subsenses, as is usually the situation). Macmillan, using a British English based corpus, uses 'unpleasant' in the relevant definition.

Comment: Seems like tangents of tangents, but I guess we agree about "sweet and sour chicken."  Personally, when I have that dish, I always skip the red sauce.  Ick.

Answer (score 0):

The four traditional tastes (sweet, sour, salt, and bitter) are often used by analogy to describe personality.

But the negative aspect of a “sour” personality doesn’t apply to food.  A sour taste comes from primarily from acids, like the citrus acid in lemon. So “sweet and sour” is an entirely correct and standard description of some dishes.

Besides the four traditional tastes, umami  (savory) is now identified as a taste, and astringency and others are under consideration. “Taste” doesn’t include the contribution the senses of smell and touch make to the appreciation of food.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste.